# Kafka unable to send/receive the message

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka

I'm trying to send a message with Kafka but everytime I send I get this message in the console:

My docker compose is:

```
  version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"


  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:  localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

My docker producer configuration:

```
 @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") //spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    private String bootstrapServers;

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory(){
       return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(
            ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory
    ){
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }

@Bean
    public NewTopic myTopic(){
        return TopicBuilder.name("Robs")
                .build();
    }
```

My consumer configuration:

```
  @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;

public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig(){
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(){
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> factory(
        ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory){
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
}
```

My controller:

```
 private final  KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;


    @PostMapping("/send")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestParam String message){
        kafkaTemplate.send("Robs",message);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Message sent to topic: Robs");

    }

 @KafkaListener(
            topics = "Robs",
            groupId = "groupId"
    )
    void listener(String data){
        System.out.println("Received: "+data);
    }
```

Console configuration output:

```
2022-11-04 11:05:18.415  INFO 10340 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
allow.auto.create.topics = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = consumer-groupId-1
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = groupId
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 45000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

ProducerConfig values:

```
acks = -1
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = producer-1
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = true
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

I get this in the console:

```
ERROR 10340 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='Ciao...... Hola' to topic Robs:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 3 record(s) for Robs-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
```

Does anybody know what I m doing wrong?
thanks!!

Comment: `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` is a deprecated property. Use `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`

Comment: @OneCricketeer should I give the value: "localhost" to this property?

Comment: Depends where you need to connect from. If your Spring code is also running in a Docker container, then no. Please refer answer in linked duplicate post